# Make menu stays hovered after move away to submenu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I made a menu with css and js code to make images and text appear when hovering on menu section, but I also need to let the colors of the menu to stay after I hover out.

here is the website: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/accueil.html

here is the css and js codes:

```
.product-block-botton {
    border-right:#ffffff solid 1px;
    text-align:center;
    vertical-align:middle;
    font-size:16px;
    padding:5px;
    height:30px;
    color:#ffffff;
}
.product-block-botton:hover {
    color:#000000;
}
.last-button {
    border:none;
}
.type1 {
    background-color:#B83E6C;
    cursor:pointer;
    width:25%;
}
```

HTML

```
<table class="product-block">
<tr>
    <td colspan="4" class="product-block-head">CHOISISSEZ VOTRE SAC
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td class="product-block-botton type1">Sac Papier Luxe</td>
    <td class="product-block-botton type1">Sac Poignées Torsadées</td>
    <td class="product-block-botton type1">Sac Poignées Plates</td>
    <td class="product-block-botton last-button type1">Sac Réutilisable</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

JS

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function(e) {
        $j('.product-block-botton').each(function(index, element) {
            $j(this).hover(function(){
                $j('.categories').hide();
                $j('.categories').eq(index).show();
            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

I hope I was clear and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean you need the colors to stay after you hover out? You want the initial link to stay white?

Comment: Hi Romain, thanks for reply, what I meant was I would like the cell to stay highlighted during the time the related photos are showing. so the visitor has no doubt regarding the category

Comment: in hover you can define two function  $(this).hover(function() {....}, function() {.....})

Comment: Hi Romain, please see the website http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/accueil.html, see the menu block right after the slide show

Comment: Hi Atal, thank you for reply, Do you mean I can remove ".hover" from the function without any problems?

Comment: I hope someone can help me with that

Answer (score 0):

Use:
      $j(this).mouseenter(function(){
       $j(this).addClass("hovered");
      });

And in CSS:

```
.product-block-botton.hovered {
   color:#000000;
 }
```

Comment: Hi Rajiv007, Thank you for editing my question and thank you for reply, but unfortunately, after using ".hovered" it still not staying black after hovering out

Comment: Use "mouseenter" instead of "hover"

Comment: I used .product-block-botton:mouseenter { color:#000000; }, then it never changed the color at all on hover, and I added the js like that:  $j(this).mouseenter(function(){ $j(this).addClass("hovered"); });

Comment: do you know why is that?

Comment: You have to make a fiddle to understand what you need